# System.InvalidOperationException while join two table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

In project i have two tables

- Restaurant (RestaurantId, Name, Adress)
- RestaurantReview (ReviewId, RestaurantId, Mark)

I want to display one restaurant and calculate its average Mark

```
var lj = (from x in _context.Restaurant
         join y in _context.RestaurantReview on x.RestaurantId equals y.RestaurantId into z
         select new
         {
              Name= x.Name,
              Total = z.Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Mark))
         }).ToList();
```

while run this code i got error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: „Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupJoin<Restaurant, RestaurantReview , int, <>f__AnonymousType4<string, double>>(
    outer: DbSet<Restaurant>, 
    inner: DbSet<RestaurantReview >, 
    outerKeySelector: (x) => x.RestaurantId, 
    innerKeySelector: (y) => y.RestaurantId, 
    resultSelector: (x, z) => new { 
        Name = x.Name , 
        Total = Average<RestaurantReview >(
            source: z, 
            selector: (x) => ToInt32(x.mark))
     })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.
```

I try use other query, but every time I get the same error

Comment: Seems that `Average(x => Convert.ToInt32...)` can't be translated. Try `Select(x => Convert.ToInt32...).Average()`.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for help. I delete this line `Total = z.Average(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Mark))` and i get this same error :( Could you answer me how to deal with this problem (fix the error or download data in a different way)?

Comment: Try to use navigation properties instead of join (`Restaurant.RestaurantReviews`). Much better anyway.

Comment: If i add in select `select restaurant.RestaurantReviews.Average(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Mark)` Will I be able to somehow get the rest of the items from the Restaurant (like Name ora Id)?

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your help, i create `select new { ...}` and get values from database and calculate Average using ``Average = restaurant.RestaurantReviews.Average(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.Mark)`` :)

Comment: Maybe you can add a self answer to show what you did. Your comments don't make it 100% clear. Also, if you accept your own answer there will be an accepted answer that *does* answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by missing in your code. Add group by in linq expression

Comment: I add code `from a in z group a by a.IdRestauracji into g` but now i have acces only to property Key or Value